# Biblatex citation order: One order in text and another in ref table

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to show citations in text in the order I add them and in the reference table in alphabetical order. I have tried `\newrefcontext` but I get an error. Is there any other solution?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxbibnames=5,maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,natbib=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{name.bib}
@book{denhartog_mechanical_1956,
    title = {Mechanical {{Vibrations}}, {{Fourth Edition}}},
    author = {Den Hartog, J. P},
    year = {1956},
    publisher = {{McGraw-Hill}}
}
@book{clough_dynamics_1975,
    title = {Dynamics of {{Structures}}},
    author = {Clough, Ray W. and Penzien, Joseph},
    year = {1975},
    publisher = {{McGraw-Hill}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{name.bib}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Body}
        Citations \autocite[e.g.,][]{denhartog_mechanical_1956,clough_dynamics_1975}.

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The reference table is fine but the citation order in the text is wrong. If I use `sorting=none` then I get the opposite result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the option `sortcites=false,` to stop `biblatex` from sorting your citations. The option `sortcites` is set to `true` by `(cite)style=authoryear-comp,` because the `-comp` feature of the style only works well if the citations are sorted in a useful order.

There is no need for `refcontext`s here, which is good, because BibTeX doesn't really support them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  sortcites=false,
  maxbibnames=5,maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits=true,
  natbib=true,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{denhartog_mechanical_1956,
  title     = {Mechanical Vibrations},
  author    = {Den Hartog, J. P},
  year      = {1956},
  publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
  edition   = {4},
}
@book{clough_dynamics_1975,
  title     = {Dynamics of Structures},
  author    = {Clough, Ray W. and Penzien, Joseph},
  year      = {1975},
  publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Citations \autocite[e.g.,][]{denhartog_mechanical_1956,clough_dynamics_1975}.

  \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations (e.g., Den Hartog, 1956; Clough and Penzien, 1975).]

Note that I replaced `style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp,` with the shorter but equivalent

```
style=authoryear-comp,
```

I also removed the `sorting=nyt,` because that is already implied by the style.

The option `firstinits` is now called `giveninits`.

With the `article` class the default English bibliography heading is "References", so there is no need for `,title={References}` in the `\printbibliography` call options.

You may want to consider switching from `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,`. With BibTeX you can only use a limited subset of `biblatex` features, the full set of features is only available with Biber. In theory the switch should be as easy as replacing `backend=bibtex,` with `backend=biber,` and then running Biber instead of BibTeX in the compilation cycle (or telling your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)).